# Jet pack navigation component get deep links programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, deep-linking, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I am using the Navigation Component in my app. I have created the graph successfully and linked it with a bottom navigation bar. I have also added deep links to my fragments to which i can redirect successfully. My question is, if it is possible to get the declared deep links of a fragment in the graph programmatically. The reason i want to do so is to check if that fragment is already visible in the screen before loading it again through the deep link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

```
val isCurrentFragmentWithDeepLink = navController.currentDestination?.hasDeepLink(uri) ?: false
```

I am checking if the current fragment destination has that deep link or no. So assuming that the deep links are unique for each fragment i am not re navigating to it

Comment: hasDeepLink not available method. Is there another way?